# Minimize sum with known product

Tags: derivatives, optimization

One of my optimization problems is to find 2 positive numbers such that the sum is minimum and the product is 182. Now, right off the bat, I doubt that the answer will be whole number factors of 182. In fact I think that square roots are going to be involved.

So here I go:

$$P = xy = 182$$
$$S = x+y$$

Get P in terms of x

$$y = S-x$$
$$P = Sx-x^2 = 182$$

Solve for S

$$S = \frac{182}{x}+x^2$$

Find critical points

$$S' = 2x-\frac{182}{x^2} = 0$$
$$x = \sqrt[3]{91}$$

Now, how did I get a cube root when the highest degree was second degree? That's odd. If anything I would have expected a square root. Well anyway I know what x is and I can plug that into the product equation solved for S and get

$$S = \frac{182}{\sqrt[3]{91}}+(\sqrt[3]{91})^2$$

And I can plug this into the equation for y and get

$$y= (\frac{182}{\sqrt[3]{91}}+(\sqrt[3]{91})^2) - \sqrt[3]{91}$$

Other than the fact that this probably isn't simplified, is this correct? Or did I make a mistake somewhere that lead to there being cube roots when I expected square roots?

Comment: Solving for $S$ should give $S=\frac{182}{x} + x$. You could avoid this by applying the quadratic formula to $Sx-x^2=182$.

Answer (score 1):

When you solved for $S$, you wrote

> $$P=Sx-x^2=182 \implies S=\frac{182}{x}+x^2$$

Your this step is wrong. It should be -

$$P=Sx-x^2=182 \implies S=\frac{182}{x}+\color{red}x$$

---

**Another approach :** You can use AM-GM Inequality to get;

$$\frac{{x+y}}{2} \ge \sqrt{xy} =\sqrt{182}$$

$$\implies x+y\ge 2\sqrt{182}$$

Comment: I see that error now. I forgot to divide the $x^2$ by $x$ and this division mistake caused me to get cube roots in the answer. So I should have gotten $S' = 1-\frac{182}{x^2}$ and thus $x = \sqrt{182}$ and since P = xy, that means that y would also be $\sqrt{182}$

Comment: @Caters Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with this.  One you made a computational error in solving for S. You have $Sx -x^2 = 182$ so if you solve for S, what you should have is $S = \frac{182}{x} +x$.  Secondly you made things more complicated anyway. If $182 = xy$, then $y = \frac{182}{x}$ and you have $S = x + \frac{182}{x}$ which makes solving for S faster.

Comment: I see that error now. I forgot to divide the $x^2$ by $x$ and this division mistake caused me to get cube roots in the answer